# mongodb c# 1.8.1 driver remove getdatabase(string name, MongoCredential credential)

Tags: c#, mongodb

In Mongodb c# 1.8.1 , there are no the method MongoServer.GetDatabase(string databaseName, MongoCredential credential) any more. The replacement is using MongoClientSetting. However, I would like to have the functionality that can different database has differenct user and password.
how to achieve that in Mongodb C# 1.8.1

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can still use different users for different databases.  You can see the documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/.

If you are instead indicating that you would like to use different users for the same database, then you'll need to create multiple MongoClient instances.  MongoClient is a logical connection to a cluster.  We cache connection pools underneath and due to the way that the MongoDB server version 2.4 now handles authentication, we needed to remove the old functionality.